# You do not have read permission to the file

Tags: texstudio

I am getting this message when i try to open a folder containing a latex report I installed text studio using the following commands in 2 different systems

```
sudo apt-get install texstudio
```

I was getting the following error message

[image]

I also tried changing permissions of the folder but also could't import the folder.

My folder structure is as follows

[image]

How to import a folder in texstudio,but i was able to open a .tex files and i was getting error because some files are in other folder

```
You have requested document class `cls/thesis', but the document class provides `thesis'.
```

Comment: What's the exact error? Usually you can right-click and open in TeXstudio.

Comment: sir i added the error message

Comment: yes sir,i tried opening by right clicking on the folder and i was getting the following error message

Comment: The error seems pretty clear this time: Your folder `cls` contains your document class which you are using. But the documentclass provides the class `thesis`. Maybe you could try to copy the class file to the directory of your tex file and then remove the cls prefix when including it.

Comment: sir, is it possible to import folder as a whole as i am using many other files similarly from other folder

Comment: @TeXnician Could you write up an answer of some sort, please?

Comment: @Troy Done (sort of).

Answer (score 1):

You showed us a warning (not an error). This says that your document class cannot be found, but the specified file provides another class (the class you want).

This warning can be prevented by copying the class file from the `cls` folder to the folder your `tex` file is in.